# How to render content in Magento 2 modal popup on frontend checkout page

Tags: modal-dialog, checkout, magento2

I have already implemented a popup modal on Shipping page of M2 checkout, which is triggered when a checkbox is clicked. This is my code for the `html` template file which is `view/frontend/web/template/checkout/shipping/gift-wrapper.html`

```
<td class="col col-method">
     <input type="checkbox" class="action action-update" data-bind="click: showFormPopUp" />
</td>
```

Here is my js code for it.

```
return Component.extend({
    defaults: {
        template: 'Magenest_Wrapper/checkout/shipping/gift-wrapper'
    },


    initialize: function () {

        var self = this;
        this._super();

    },

    showFormPopUp : function() {
        options.buttons =  [
            {
                text: $t('Cancel'),
                class: 'action secondary action-hide-popup',
                click: function () {
                    this.closeModal();
                }
            }
        ];

        var popup = modal(options, $('#popup-modal'));

        $('#popup-modal').modal('openModal');
    }

});
```

Now the modal window is obviously empty.

I have a collection of products. What is the solution to show them on
the modal window?

Comment: What do you mean with "show them"? Modal is a simple <div> and you could fill its html with everything.